# How to make clock in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and OOP in general. I need to make simple digital clock as homework. I have to use class. It was easier to me to make it in JS, so I did it and it works fine. Now I'm trying to "reverse" it to TypeScript. I also have to add functionality of changing time zones.

Please help!

My working JS version looks like this:

```
var clock = document.getElementById('clock');

function Clock() {
  var time = new Date();
  var hours = time.getHours().toString();
  var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
  var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();

  if (hours.length < 2) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }

  if (minutes.length < 2) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds.length < 2) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }

  var clockStr = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;

  clock.textContent = clockStr;

}

Clock();
setInterval(Clock, 1000);
```

My not working code in TypeScript looks like this:

```
class Clock {

    hours:number;
    minutes:number;
    seconds:number;

    constructor(hours:number, minutes:number, seconds:number) {

        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;

    }

    print() {

        if (hours.length < 2) {
          hours = '0' + hours;
        }

        if (minutes.length < 2) {
          minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }

        if (seconds.length < 2) {
          seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }

        var clockStr = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;

    }

}

function timeGenerate() {

    let time = new Date();
    let hours = time.getHours();
    let minutes = time.getMinutes();
    let seconds = time.getSeconds();

}

function clockRun() {

    timeGenerate();
    let newClock = new Clock(hours, minutes, seconds);
    newClock.print();

}


clockRun();
setInterval(clockRun, 1000);

document.getElementById('tsClock').innerHTML = newClock;
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Typescript Clock</title>

    <style>
        body {
        background-color: royalblue;    
        font-family: 'Lato';
        margin-top: 300px;
        text-align: center;
        color: ivory;
        }

        #clock {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 100px;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="tsClock"></h1>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, which means all valid JS is valid TS.  
For starters, the arguments here are all undefined `new Clock(hours, minutes, seconds);`

Comment: some non typescript magic i made ages ago: https://gottz.de/uhr.htm https://gottz.de/binuhr.htm https://gottz.de/analoguhr.htm

Comment: @GottZ this is cool! Can you share code?

Comment: @s-kaczmarek just view the source. thats all the code there is. it's pretty old stuff though. also that vw, vh switch could be replaced with vmin and vmax (css) i did not knew about this at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript, but not the other way around.

In your TypeScript there are some scoping issues.

In the following function, you're declaring 4 variables that only live inside the scope of this function.  Returns undefined.

```
function timeGenerate() {
    let time = new Date();
    let hours = time.getHours();
    let minutes = time.getMinutes();
    let seconds = time.getSeconds();
}
```

Here you're calling the `timeGenerate` function which doesn't do anything, creating a new clock with undefined variables, and calling `print()`.

```
function clockRun() {
    timeGenerate();
    let newClock = new Clock(hours, minutes, seconds);
    newClock.print();
}


clockRun();
setInterval(clockRun, 1000);
```

Here's a working, minimal example (keep it simple!)

```js
    class Clock {
    // Declare a class variable of type "Element" called el
    el: Element;

    /**
     * Called when "new" is invoked, you'll pass your target element here.
     * @param element Target element to update
     */
    constructor(element) {
        this.el = element;

        // Immediately kick off a setInterval to this objects "run" method,
        // every 1000ms like you had before.
        setInterval(() => this.run(), 1000)
    }
    
    /**
     * This *could* be in the constructor, but for seperation of duties we'll
     * make it a method.  This method is invoked every ~1000ms (JavaScript timers
     * aren't perfect).
     */
    run() {
        var time = new Date();
        // Don't need to call toString, but it's fine here. When you start
        // concatenating numbers onto strings they get converted anyway.
        var hours = time.getHours().toString();
        var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
        var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();
        
        // Your previous logic.
        if (hours.length < 2) {
        hours = '0' + hours;
        }
    
        if (minutes.length < 2) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }
    
        if (seconds.length < 2) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }
        var clockStr = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
        
        // Update this class' "el" variable as before.
        this.el.textContent = clockStr;
    }
    }

    // Create a new instance of Clock, passing in your target DOM element.
    const clock = new Clock(document.getElementById('clock'))
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vyaqxg)

Comment: During compilation I get error: "app3.ts(24,11): error TS2339: Property 'textContent' does not exist on type 'Clock'." What about this line: "document.getElementById('tsClock').innerHTML = newClock;" I think it should be placed somewhare, doesn't it? This code is not working, I just have plain site with background.

Comment: Sorry, I had to rush to get home and it was a bit incomplete. Try the above, check the codepen.

Comment: Now it works! Strange thing is that this clock is unstyled. Could you please give me some comments to this code? I need to understand it 100%

Comment: Added comments.  It's unstyled because I didn't grab your CSS. This is just the TS solution.

Comment: CSS problem was my mistake - I have miss typed id. Thanks for comments. I will study this code today. Do you have idea how to make change time zone button? I have made something like this: https://codepen.io/s-kaczmarek/pen/eyzBjQ I have no idea how to generate new clock and add +3 to hour value.

Answer (score 2):

Just before we go through your code. You need to know that typescript can't be read by the browser. So you should compile it to a JavaScript (ES 5). Therefore your **index.html** should import your compiled JavaScript not the typescript file.

Now let's go to your code:

```
class Clock {

    hours:number;
    minutes:number;
    seconds:number;

    constructor(hours:number, minutes:number, seconds:number) {

        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;

        this.clockRun();
        setInterval(this.clockRun, 1000);

        document.getElementById('tsClock').innerHTML = newClock;

    }

    print() {

        if (hours.length < 2) {
          hours = '0' + hours;
        }

        if (minutes.length < 2) {
          minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }

        if (seconds.length < 2) {
          seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }

        var clockStr = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;

    }

}

 timeGenerate() {

    let time = new Date();
    let hours = time.getHours();
    let minutes = time.getMinutes();
    let seconds = time.getSeconds();

}

 clockRun() {

    this.timeGenerate();
    let newClock = new Clock(hours, minutes, seconds);
    this.print();

}
```

Comment: Yeah, my index.html imports app.js and I know how to compile .ts to .js thanks for reminder.